# APP_INITIALIZER doesn`t work, service is undefined

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, angular8

Im using APP_INITIALIZER in my Angular application, when the application loads, doesn't work. I need to perform some initialization logic before the aplication is initialized.
I'm using APP_INITIALIZER  get configuration for config.json

This is my app.service.ts under the folder src/app:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from "rxjs";
import { concatMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AppService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  init(): Promise<Object> {  
    return this.http.get('./assets/config.json')
      .pipe(
        tap((config: any) => {
          console.log('Rutas config.json', config);         
        })
      ).toPromise();
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,  
    InicioComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
   BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),   
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],  
  providers: [   
   { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initAppService, deps: [AppService], multi: true },    
  ],  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
export function initAppService(appService: AppService) {
  return () => {appService.init()};
}
```

When I run the app, I get the error in line "appservice.init()", appservice is undefined:

Any idea?

Comment: You need the initAppService factory to return a function that returns a promise. Yours returns a void function.

Answer (score 0):

It's about how you return promise in the `initAppService`.

Please make following changes to your code:

Ether remove curly braces, because you don't need them:

```
export function initAppService(appService: AppService) {
  return async () => appService.init();
}
```

Or, add `return` statement explicitly:

```
export function initAppService(appService: AppService) {
  return async () => {
    return appService.init();
  }
}
```